# getrandmax() why 32767 limitiation on windows?

Tags: php, random

PHP returns largest possible random value 32767 on windows?

What is constraint on windows?

```
echo getrandmax(); //32767
```

Comment: rand calls a system rand function that dates back to the ark -- or at least when most minicomputers had a 16-bit wordlength.  If you want a better random number generator use the Mersenne Twister one: mt_rand().  It's mt_getrandmax() is 2^31-1.

Comment: Or rather, it's the largest possible seed. There are only 32767 distinct random values between 1 and 250000, or 1 and 1 billion, which is rather stupid. (That's where the Mersenne Twister comes in!)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the PHP source-code, [**`getrandmax()`**](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/rand.c#350) is defined as :

```
PHP_FUNCTION(getrandmax)
{
    if (zend_parse_parameters_none() == FAILURE) {
        return;
    }

    RETURN_LONG(PHP_RAND_MAX);
}
```

And [**`PHP_RAND_MAX`**](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/php_rand.h#40) is defined as :

```
#define PHP_RAND_MAX RAND_MAX
```

[**`RAND_MAX`**](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/php_rand.h#33) itself being defined as :

```
/* System Rand functions */
#ifndef RAND_MAX
#define RAND_MAX (1<<15)
#endif
```

So, if there is an `RAND_MAX` defined, it is used...

... And, on Windows with Visual Studio, there is indeed a [**`RAND_MAX`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dfe3bzd.aspx) defined *(quoting)* :

> The constant `RAND_MAX` is the maximum value that can be returned by
>   the `rand` function. **`RAND_MAX` is defined as the value `0x7fff`**.

So, basically, `getrandmax()` returns `32767` because that's how it's defined on Windows -- and PHP often uses what the underlying system exports.

Comment: beat me by time. I was just looking at the source